# SQL alias select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to reorder my query to have the name in the first column, but I still need the rest of the columns populated as well.
How would you implement an alias in oracle to achieve this query?

```
select s.name, s.* from table as s
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you would have to specify all column names if you want them in a certain order.

Comment: `SELECT *` is a bad idea almost in all cases when it comes to live code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way around this, you must specify all columns in the order you would like them.

```
select s.name, s.column1, s.column2, ... from table as s
```

Comment: Okay that is what I assumed just don't know the full capabilities of sql yet. Have a good one.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: @DanBracuk This question was legible, contained a code example and was monitored by the questioner, which makes it better than 70% of the questions on Stack Overflow.  Cut the guy some slack, we all were in his place at one point in time.  In fact, I would argue this question demonstrates creativity and exploration, should the OP be criticized for that?